# Type of hypothesis test in scipy.stats.linregress

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statistics

Python documentation notes that this is a two tailed test but there is no comment on what kind of test it is. Is it a T Test, Z Test, F Test...

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the *t*-test.  In the latest version of scipy, you can find the code in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_stats_mstats_common.py

The relevant code in `linregress` is:

```
    df = n - 2
    t = r * np.sqrt(df / ((1.0 - r + TINY)*(1.0 + r + TINY)))
    prob = 2 * distributions.t.sf(np.abs(t), df)
```